# Can't get dataset from raster map(.tiff) using GDAL on VS2012 C++

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, osgeo, visual-c++

Can someone help me regarding this problem?

It seem the code can't read the data set of my raster map.It will throw this exception (popup to break or continue).

> Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F63298A in GdalTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

```
// GdalTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//


#include "cpl_conv.h" // for CPLMalloc()
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "gdal.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "gdal_priv.h"


using namespace std;

class GDALMajorObject;
class GDALDataset;
class GDALRasterBand;
class GDALDriver;
class GDALRasterAttributeTable;
class GDALProxyDataset;
class GDALProxyRasterBand;
class GDALAsyncReader;




int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     GDALAllRegister(); 

    GDALDataset *poDataset;
    char* Raster = new char[256];
    double  adfGeoTransform[6];

    Raster = "@ C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DSI REFERENCE\\Map Data\\Raster\\4257.tiff";

    poDataset = (GDALDataset *) GDALOpen(Raster, GA_ReadOnly )CPL_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
    if( poDataset == NULL )
    {
        cout<<"Damn it"<<endl;
    }         

    cout<<( "Driver: %s/%s\n",
        poDataset->GetDriver()->GetDescription(),
        poDataset->GetDriver()->GetMetadataItem( GDAL_DMD_LONGNAME ) );

    cout<<( "Size is %dx%dx%d\n",
        poDataset->GetRasterXSize(), poDataset->GetRasterYSize(),
        poDataset->GetRasterCount() );

    if( poDataset->GetProjectionRef()  != NULL )
    cout<<( "Projection is `%s'\n", poDataset->GetProjectionRef() );

    if( poDataset->GetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform ) == CE_None )
    {
        cout<<( "Origin = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[0], adfGeoTransform[3] );
        cout<<( "Pixel Size = (%.6f,%.6f)\n",
            adfGeoTransform[1], adfGeoTransform[5] );
    }


    // make it 256 bytes for a string length of 255 plus null (\0) terminator



    // your code
    delete[] Raster;// release the memory VERY IMPORTANT

}
```

**EDIT**

It show this error when i try run the program.[image]

Then I try to debug the code line by line. It got error reading character on string for this code line

```
char* Raster = new char[256];
```

when i about to debug another line it will jump to newaop.cpp tab.

```
// newaop -- operator new[](size_t) REPLACEABLE
#include <new>

void *__CRTDECL operator new[](size_t count) _THROW1(std::bad_alloc)
    {   // try to allocate count bytes for an array
    return (operator new(count));
    }
```

then i keep debug it will go debug to tab dbgdel.cpp until it stop at dbgheap.c then throw this

> memset.asm not found

Comment: Raster = "@ C:\\Use.. shouldn't have the @ inside the quote, try Raster = "C:\\Use.. what line is your error on? Your exception is a null reference exception (a pointer is null or 0x0000000000000000, which is protected memory). Try step debugging and see where it breaks.

Comment: I already delete the @ symbol.From edit above i don't get thrown any exception anymore. But it give Debug  Assertion Failed. It cause error when I try to debug line by line. This because of the code or the program can't access my raster(.tiff) map file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is weird, I'm guessing here. From my working code:

```
    char* OutPath  = new char[FullPathMax]; // const int FullPathMax = 4096;
    wcstombs(OutPath,argv[2],FullPathMax);  // put the 2nd argument into OutPath

    GDALAllRegister(); // setup GDAL ready to use

    char* MaskName = new char[MaxLength];     // assign memory for the file path
    sprintf(MaskName,"%s\\Mask.img",OutPath); // change to "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DSI REFERENCE\\Map Data\\Raster\\4257.tiff"

    GDALDataset* MaskDS = (GDALDataset*)GDALOpen(MaskName,GDALAccess::GA_Update);
    if (MaskDS == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Damn it"<<endl; // I like this error message you used.
        delete[] OutPath;      // free resources
        delete[] MaskName;     // free resources
        return -1;             // exit here on error
    }
    MaskDS->GetGeoTransform(GeoTransform);
```

As you can see I don't use `=` to set the string into the `char*`, which is solely because I want to use an argument so don't already know what the string is, which could be where your problem lies.. I had to read up on it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963888/c-char-initialization-in-constructor from the answer by Jerry Coffin and http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/106589/ the equals assignment `Raster = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DSI REFERENCE\\Map Data\\Raster\\4257.tiff";` is valid, but being depreciated.

In C++ [there is a difference between `string` and `char*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352099/stdstring-to-char) but also Windows has `wchar*` which is a pointer to a unicode character array, depending on your codepage your literal may be *unicode* and not going into your `char*` properly. Have a shot at `wcstombs(Raster,&"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DSI REFERENCE\\Map Data\\Raster\\4257.tiff",wcsnlen(&"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\DSI REFERENCE\\Map Data\\Raster\\4257.tiff"));` using [wcstombs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw.aspx) to convert multibyte to char array with the multibyte string length [wcsnlen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50ty2zh.aspx) and see if that helps. If not post a question on StackOverflow, with a link to this thread, as this appears to be more C++ than GIS.